# What is required to show $S = \{e^{i n \theta}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a basis for $L^2([0, 2\pi])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, schauder-basis

I have read some papers that make use of a 'Fourier basis' when decomposing some functions, but I am wondering whether there is more depth behind that phrase and what can we rigorously say about this basis. Suppose we want to be rigorous. In that case is it ok to simply say that the set of functions

$S = \{e^{i n \theta}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\},$

forms a basis for $L^2([0, 2\pi])$ because any function $f \in L^2([0, 2\pi])$ can be represented as a linear combination of cosines and sines? Or is it necessary to show that the set of functions $S$ is a Hamel or Schauder basis for the space $L^2([0, 2\pi])$? If it's the latter, which type of basis is this set of functions $S$, Hamel or Schauder? And how do we show it is a basis?

Comment: The term you want to look up is "orthonormal basis" (in a Hilbert space). This is a particularly convenient kind of Schauder basis. Proofs of the relevant results should be in just abour any book that treats Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that your set forms an orthonormal system can be verified directly by a calculation. The hard thing is to show that this system is complete (or, in other words, that $\operatorname{span}(S)$ which is the space of trigonometric polynomials is dense in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm). One way to do it is to use first the [Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem to show that the space of trigonometric polynomials is dense in $C[0,2\pi]$ with respect to the supremum norm and then use the density of continuous functions in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ (with respect to the $L^2$ norm) and the fact that converges in the supremum norm implies converges in the $L^2$ norm to deduce the required result.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that procedure. Do you know whether Zorn's Lemma or the Axiom of Choice need to invoked at some stage using the procedure you suggested or does this method avoid the need for them? I have read that there are issues when constructing a basis for an infinite dimensional space as you can always keep adding more linearly independent vectors to a set you are trying to make a basis out of!

Comment: @eurocoder: Here you have a concrete collection in a concrete vector space and you prove it forms a complete basis. This is not the same situation as trying to construct a Hamel basis (or an orthonormal system) for an abstract vector space by adding linearly independent vectors. However, I don't know much about axiomatic set theory so I can't tell you if the results used (say Stone-Weierstrass) depend on the Axiom of Choice or not.

Comment: @eurocoder : If you know that a Hilbert space is separable, then you can apply Gram-Schmidt to the countable dense subset, throwing out dependent elements as you go, and arrive at an orthonormal basis. So the assumption that you have a countable dense set bypasses the need for full-blown Axiom of Choice. In other cases, Zorn's lemma is needed to produce a maximal orthonormal set (which is then shown to be complete.)

Comment: Excellent answers, that clears up some things, thanks! Just to be 100% clear, the Axiom of Choice is not needed when the set is countable, if the set was uncountable we would need the Axiom of Choice?